# How to compare 2 cells with delimited items in each and output the difference in items?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

What is the most efficient way to compare 2 cells with delimited items in each cell in excel?

For example, I want to check if each color in Set A appears in Set B and vice versa. Ideally, I would like a separate column, say Result Set A - to output which item from Set A **is missing** in Set B. similarly, in another column called Result Set B - output which item from Set B is missing in Set A.

Example

| Colors Set A | Colors Set B |
| --- | --- |
| red;blue;green | yellow;purple;red |
| white;green | yellow;red |

Goal

| Colors Set A | Colors Set B | Result Set A | Result Set B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red;blue;green | yellow;purple;red | blue;green | yellow;purple |
| white;green;red | yellow;red | white;green | yellow |

Note: As of right now, I do this very manual: Using excel Text to Columns with delimiter, then doing COUNTIF to check if each cell exist in the opposite range - very complicated for larger data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function would do this for you.

```
Function compare(setA As String, setB As String)

    Const delim As String = ";"
    
    For Each strPartA In Split(setA, delim)
        found = False
        For Each strPartB In Split(setB, delim)
            If Trim(strPartA) = Trim(strPartB) Then found = True
        Next
        If found = False Then compare = compare & strPartA & delim
    Next
    
    If Len(compare) > 0 Then compare = Left(compare, Len(compare) - 1)
    
End Function
```

You can use this as a UDF - i.e. enter it as a formula, e.g. if A1 contains "red;blue;green" and B1 contains "yellow;purple;red" then you can enter this formula in C1:

```
=compare(A1,B1)             to return "blue;green"
```

and this in D1

```
=compare(B1,A1)             to return "yellow;purple"
```

Or alternatively you could write this into a routine:

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each c In Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
            c.Offset(, 2) = compare(c.Value, c.Offset(, 1).Value)
            c.Offset(, 3) = compare(c.Offset(, 1).Value, c.Value)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: CLR - you've answered my question and have saved me hours in analysis. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Keep in mind though, it will not deal with typos correctly and if one 'colour' appears more than once in either cell, it will remove all copies of it from the other cell.

Comment: Which part of the macro is causing the removal of all copies/duplicates in the cell?

Comment: It's just the way it works. It doesn't compare each item for the equivalent item in the other set, i.e. it doesn't check item1A against item1B, item2A against item2B. Instead, it checks item1A against every item in B, then item2A against every item in B. So it SetA contains 2 lots of Blue, and SetB contains only 1, both will be removed from SetA.